# Problems compiling VASP

Tags: compiling, gcc, compiler

I'm trying to compile VASP 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and running into issues. I believe I'm most the way there but when I run the make command it seems to bottle out with out a specific error. I am unable to run make install:
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.

This is very new to me so I am struggling to really get any where at this stage.

makefile.include

```
# Precompiler options
CPP_OPTIONS= -DMPI -DHOST=\"IFC91_ompi\" -DIFC \
             -DCACHE_SIZE=4000 -Davoidalloc \
             -DMPI_BLOCK=8000 -DscaLAPACK -Duse_collective \
             -DnoAugXCmeta -Duse_bse_te \
             -Duse_shmem -Dtbdyn

CPP        = gcc -E -P -C $*$(FUFFIX) >$*$(SUFFIX) $(CPP_OPTIONS)

FC         = mpif90
FCL        = $(FC)

FREE       = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none

FFLAGS     = 
OFLAG      = -O2
OFLAG_IN   = $(OFLAG)
DEBUG      = -O0

LIBDIR     = /usr/lib
BLAS       = -L$(LIBDIR) -lblas
LAPACK     = -L$(LIBDIR) -llapack
BLACS      = -L$(LIBDIR) -lblacs-openmpi -lblacsCinit-openmpi
SCALAPACK  = -L$(LIBDIR) -lscalapack-openmpi $(BLACS)

FFTW       = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfftw3f_mpi

OBJECTS    = fftmpi.o fftmpi_map.o fft3dfurth.o  fft3dlib.o

INCS       =-I/usr/local/include

LLIBS      = $(SCALAPACK) $(LAPACK) $(BLAS) $(FFTW)

OBJECTS_O1 += fft3dfurth.o fftw3d.o fftmpi.o fftmpiw.o chi.o
OBJECTS_O2 += fft3dlib.o

# For what used to be vasp.5.lib
CPP_LIB    = $(CPP)
FC_LIB     = $(FC) 
CC_LIB     = gcc
CFLAGS_LIB = -O
FFLAGS_LIB = -O1
FREE_LIB   = $(FREE)

OBJECTS_LIB= linpack_double.o getshmem.o

# Normally no need to change this
SRCDIR     = ../../src
BINDIR     = ../../bin
```

End of the output from make command

```
cp makefile.include lib
make -C lib
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl/lib'
make libdmy.a
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl/lib'
make[4]: `libdmy.a' is up to date.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl/lib'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl/lib'
gcc -E -P -C main.F >main.f90 -DMPI -DHOST=\"IFC91_ompi\" -DIFC -DCACHE_SIZE=4000 -Davoidalloc -DMPI_BLOCK=8000 -DscaLAPACK -Duse_collective -DnoAugXCmeta -Duse_bse_te -Duse_shmem -Dtbdyn
mpif90 -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none  -O0 -I/usr/local/include -c main.f90
rm -f vasp
mpif90 -o vasp base.o mpi.o smart_allocate.o xml.o constant.o jacobi.o main_mpi.o scala.o asa.o lattice.o poscar.o ini.o mgrid.o xclib.o vdw_nl.o xclib_grad.o radial.o pseudo.o gridq.o ebs.o mkpoints.o wave.o wave_mpi.o wave_high.o spinsym.o symmetry.o symlib.o lattlib.o random.o nonl.o nonlr.o nonl_high.o dfast.o choleski2.o mix.o hamil.o xcgrad.o xcspin.o potex1.o potex2.o constrmag.o cl_shift.o relativistic.o LDApU.o paw_base.o metagga.o egrad.o pawsym.o pawfock.o pawlhf.o rhfatm.o hyperfine.o paw.o mkpoints_full.o charge.o Lebedev-Laikov.o stockholder.o dipol.o solvation.o pot.o dos.o elf.o tet.o tetweight.o hamil_rot.o chain.o dyna.o k-proj.o sphpro.o us.o core_rel.o aedens.o wavpre.o wavpre_noio.o broyden.o dynbr.o reader.o writer.o tutor.o xml_writer.o brent.o stufak.o fileio.o opergrid.o stepver.o chgloc.o fast_aug.o fock_multipole.o fock.o mkpoints_change.o subrot_cluster.o sym_grad.o mymath.o npt_dynamics.o subdftd3.o internals.o dynconstr.o dimer_heyden.o dvvtrajectory.o vdwforcefield.o hamil_high.o nmr.o pead.o subrot.o subrot_scf.o paircorrection.o force.o pwlhf.o gw_model.o optreal.o steep.o rmm-diis.o davidson.o david_inner.o electron.o rot.o electron_all.o shm.o pardens.o optics.o constr_cell_relax.o stm.o finite_diff.o elpol.o hamil_lr.o rmm-diis_lr.o subrot_lr.o lr_helper.o hamil_lrf.o elinear_response.o ilinear_response.o linear_optics.o setlocalpp.o wannier.o electron_OEP.o electron_lhf.o twoelectron4o.o gauss_quad.o m_unirnk.o varpro.o minimax.o mlwf.o ratpol.o screened_2e.o wave_cacher.o chi_base.o wpot.o local_field.o ump2.o ump2kpar.o fcidump.o ump2no.o bse_te.o bse.o acfdt.o chi.o sydmat.o rmm-diis_mlr.o linear_response_NMR.o wannier_interpol.o linear_response.o lcao_bare.o wnpr.o dmft.o auger.o dmatrix.o fftmpi.o fftmpi_map.o fft3dfurth.o  fft3dlib.o main.o  -Llib -ldmy -L/usr/lib -lscalapack-openmpi -L/usr/lib -lblacs-openmpi -lblacsCinit-openmpi -L/usr/lib -llapack -L/usr/lib -lblas -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfftw3f_mpi 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/scienceadmin/Documents/VASP/src/vasp.5.4.1/build/ncl'
```

Comment: There is no "install" in a way that you can type 'make install' http://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/Installation_VASP.html

Comment: Good find, I completely missed this doc and was using the README. Thanks Knud!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already compiled it. The `make` is what compiles. The `make install` simply copies the compiled executables and associated files to their target directories on your system.

From what you describe, it sounds like what you are compiling simply doesn't have an `install` script. I haven't compiled this particular package myself but such third party tools often don't have an install script since they're more of a specialized geek tool and the authors expect you'll know how to use them.

Look for a `bin` directory or, alternatively, for executable files inside the `src` directory and then execute those files. For example:

```
./bin/vasp
```

Comment: Hi Terdon, your self and Knud were correct, there is no install script for vasp. I'l have to put this down my inexperience. Thank you greatly for your time.